# Xubuntu 13.04: How to hide backup files on desktop?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, desktop-environments

I just changed from Ubuntu 13.04 to Xubuntu 13.04 in an attempt to improve the performance of my slightly outdated notebook. Everything apparently went fine except that my desktop is now cluttered with temporary backup files. I can easily remove them in the file manager by unclicking "Show hidden files", but this does not have any effect on the desktop itself.

In want of a better solution, I have considered redirecting my temporary backup files to a folder other than the Desktop folder, but I am not sure how to do that either.

If anybody knows how to either hide the backup files from my desktop, redirect them to another folder, or work some other kind of magic, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

To hide a file or folder just rename it and put a "." in front of its name

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/file1 /home/user/Desktop/.file1
```

this will hide files/folders.

Or

To move the backup files to another location use the move command in terminal

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/file1 /place/where-to/move
```

To move particular type of files like .sql files

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/*.sql /plcae/to/move
```

To move file ending with "~" use

```
mv /home/user/Desktop/*~ /plcae/to/move
```

Comment: Your advice works just fine for single files, but is there a way to automate the process for temp files in general (e.g. for all files ending with "~") as new files keep appearing on the desktop as I open and close documents?

Comment: I have edited the answer, you mean to say that after opening the files the temporary files doesn't gets removed and still show on the desktop?

Comment: Yes, whenever I use a file on the desktop a temporary backup file ending in "~" is created and saved on the desktop. This is not a problem in the file manager where those files are easily hidden by unclicking "Show hidden files", but this has no effect on the desktop screen itself. Somehow, it appears that the desktop screen and the file manager are inconsistent when it comes to showing or not showing hidden files.